# ListView with PaddingTop has Rows Removed too Quickly when Scrolling (Android 2.3 / Gingerbread)

Tags: android, listview, android-2.3-gingerbread

The title says it all.  On Android Gingerbread with a listview that has paddingTop set, then the top row of the listview is always removed when it has been scrolled past the padding, not when it has actually exited the listview bounds.  This has been fixed in later versions it appears, but it is definitely annoying in gingerbread because the top view keeps falling off the screen spontaneously instead of sliding quietly off of the page bounds as it should.  This isn't hugely noticeable except when you have set a rather large paddingTop, like my use case requires.

Has anyone seen this before or figured out a fix for it?  Thanks!!!

Comment: A bit of a kludge, but how about faking padding with an invisible empty view as part of the layout?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but would require a lot of code changes.  Adding a headerview to the listview might have a similar result...